# Selenium / Python wait beforer entering Keys.RETURN

Tags: python, selenium

In selenium, I want to wait for 5 seconds before code to press the enter. I understand I have to use WebDriverWait and here is my attempt on it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/Desktop/projects/chromedriver")
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')

WebDriverWait(elem, 5)

elem.send_keys('stackoverflow' + Keys.RETURN) # How to force selenium for 5 seconds before pressing enter
```

Comment: One of the main mission of _Automation Testing_ is to reduce the time lost in between performing steps through  _Manual Testing_. Why would you `want to wait for 5 seconds`? What is your exact _usecase_?

Comment: I'm not actually testing but trying to make a web scraper where I want to wait for all the data to get loaded including any JS / Ajax before pressing enter. I hope it clarifies.

Comment: Then you should have been waited for the webelement `elem = browser.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')` to receive  text but not to wait before `elem.send_keys('stackoverflow' + Keys.RETURN)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a specific wait time, you could use time.sleep()

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')

time.sleep(5)

elem.send_keys('stackoverflow' + Keys.RETURN)
```

Make sure to import time with all your other import packages.

Comment: Yes thats what I ended up doing myself. Thx